# What are the causes of HTTP 406 error

Tags: http, http-error, http-status-code-406

We are using newrelic to monitor our enterprise website.

We have been noticing a large number of **HTTP 406** error logged in newrelic. These error are especially occurring for JPG images.

Weird thing is when I copy paste the jpg URL it works fine with no issues.

Could someone point me to right direction, how this can be fixed?

Comment: HTTP 406 means that the content type of the requested object is not compatible with the accepted content types specified in the "Accept:" header in the HTTP request.

Comment: thanks but could you please clarify with an example. e.g. abc.jpg was requested then where does the issue lies?

Comment: I'd say that such a specific question cannot be answered here on SO, since this appears to be in internal issue of that software you use. Why don't you ask their support? I mean that is what it is there for...

Comment: I came across the same issue and I can reproduce it as well. The url from New Relic is working fine in the browser, however, if I use Fiddler and set the Header to accept json only with 'Accept: application/json', the result, obviously, will be HTTP406. @NilPun were you be able to figure out the source of these requests? I suspect that bots doing this.

Comment: @gaborhodi I just came to the same conclusion that these are being triggered by bots. In my case it was the SemrushBot.